# Need MySQL query results as array of JSONs, NOT array of arrays holding JSONs

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, json

I'm running MySQL 8 in a dev environment, learning as I go. I'm running a very simple PHP 7 RestAPI.

Here is how I'm executing a simply MySQL lookup:

```
$blockStmt = 'SELECT JSON_ARRAY(JSON_OBJECT("value", titleId, "title", titleDesc)) 
              FROM titleTable ORDER BY titleDesc';
$preppedQuery = $db->query($blockStmt);
$blockResult = mysqli_fetch_all($preppedQuery);
print_r(json_encode($blockResult));
```

Here is how the result set is being returned by the print_r

```
[
  [{"title": "Title 1", "value": "title1"}],
  [{"title": "Title 2", "value": "title2"}],
  [{"title": "Title 3", "value": "title3"}]
]
```

Here is how I WANT the results to be formatted:

```
[
  {"title": "Title 1", "value": "title1"},
  {"title": "Title 2", "value": "title2"},
  {"title": "Title 3", "value": "title3"}
]
```

I've been working with the various JSON commands and can't seem to keep MySQL from encapsulating each result row as an array containing a single JSON, instead of just returning it as a JSON only.

Any tips? Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Please remove JSON_ARRAY from query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the JSON functions, just return the columns that you want. `mysqli_fetch_all()` will then return associative arrays, and `json_encode()` will convert them to JSON.

```
$blockStmt = 'SELECT titleId AS value, titleDesc AS title 
              FROM titleTable ORDER BY titleDesc';
$preppedQuery = $db->query($blockStmt);
$blockResult = mysqli_fetch_all($preppedQuery, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
print_r(json_encode($blockResult));
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar! Removing all the JSON functions and adding the MYSQLI_ASSOC value to the fetch fixed it. Thanks for your help!